# How can I translate this simple ruby script to C++?

Tags: c++, ruby, arrays

I have such code:

```
class Container
  def initialize
    @container = []
  end

  def add(element)
    @container << element
  end

end

class Element
  def initialize(container)
    @container.add(self)
  end
end

c = Container.new
e1 = Element.new(c)
e2 = Element.new(c)
```

how to write it in c++ with **using only cstdio (no vector)** (I need it for my school)?

Comment: Converting to C brings up a lot of questions. Are you wanting container[] to be a dynamic array? a linked list? a pre-set size array? That determines how your C++ classes will be setup.

Comment: Container should be normal table like Container[] container = new Container[100000]; in java (as I remember java...)

Comment: Why the "without using anything"? Can you use a keyboard?

Comment: What have you done or tried? You just said this is homework - we won't do your homework for you unless you attempt it yourself.

Comment: Sorry Kerrek SB, it is 2 AM here.

Comment: @Marlon - homework is much more complicated, and I solved it using Ruby. The problem is I have never use C++ (only C few years ago). Only C or C++ is allowed, so I will appriciate some help.

Comment: It'll be easier to get an answer if you add the skeleton of the code that you wrote, even if it's incomplete, so that others can comment and correct. But it's higly improbable to get a full answer from this question as it is now because: a) it's not fair to ask others to do your work for free b) you'll learn nothing if you get a complete solution, which is the purpose of the homework anyway

Comment: Is that really how one adds objects to an array in ruby?  That's horrifying to my C++ eyes!

Answer (score 3):

Here are some hints.

```
class Element
{
    /* I don't know ruby but that separation of concerns is perverse. 
    Element does not need to know anything about Container.
    Nothing needed here. */
};

class Container 
{
    private:
        Element* c;
        unsigned int count;
    public:
        Container() { /* Research initialiser lists and complete this stub */ }
        ~Container(){ /* Dynamic memory must be freed */ }

        void Add(const Element& e) { 
            /* Does the container already have an item in it? 
            How will that affect an Add operation? */ 
        }
};

int main ()
{
    /*
        This should be easy ...
    */
}

/* Once you've finished this and have time for more, 
research the Rule of Three and fix the memory leak bug 
in the Container class */
```

Comment: Missing a copy-constructor and an assignment operator. Just use `std::vector`.

Comment: It's not Ruby that is perverse, it's the design used.

Comment: @Daemin I thought it might have been.